# Proper structure for NPM package containing only typescript models?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, github-package-registry

I am trying to create a shared project / NPM package that will contain shared typescript models across a couple different projects. I managed to get the package published to GitHub and am able to install it. I can't seem to figure out the correct folder structure and .tsconfig values.

I want to be able to import my models based on the folder they reside in. For example: `import { User } from @org/project-name/users`

My current folder structure looks like this.
[image]

Where each model contains something like this `export type Organization = {...}`

And the index.ts file in each folder aggregates the individual model exports. Like `export { Organization } from './organization';`

My .tsconfig has the following options set:[image: tsconfig]

How can I build the typescript project and publish the npm package in such a way that I can import the correct model based on it's parent folder like mentioned above?